# How to get this logitech lua script to move my mouse left, then to the right and keep on repeating that until mouse button 1 is no longer pressed

Tags: lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

I have picked up learning lua. This is my first programming language. I have written this script myself using logitechs lua api documentation to learn the language.

I wrote 2 similar codes to try and approach my problem from two different ways. Both have failed.

Code#1

```html
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)

function OnEvent(event, arg)
    --OutputLogMessage("Event: "..event.." Arg: "..arg.."\n")
    if IsKeyLockOn("capslock") then
        repeat
            if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
                repeat
                    PressAndReleaseKey("p")
                    Sleep(10)
                    MoveMouseRelative(-10,0)
                    Sleep(10)
                    MoveMouseRelative(10,0)
                    Sleep(10)
                until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
            end
        until not IsKeyLockOn("capslock")
    end
end
```

This code is meant to repeatedly press the keyboard button "p" and repeatedly move the mouse left, then right until LMB is no longer being pressed. The method I was going for was to use MoveMouseRelative to go left, then pause for 10ms-Sleep(10) then use MoveMouseRelative to go right and just repeat that loop. What I noticed is that it is moving from left to right too fast, and when I increased the delay of the sleep, it also increased the delay of "P" being pressed. So I think I need to find a way to make the program move from left to right slower, without affecting the speed at which "P" is pressed

Now the 2nd attempt
Code#2

```html
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)

function OnEvent(event, arg)
    --OutputLogMessage("Event: "..event.." Arg: "..arg.."\n")
    if IsKeyLockOn("capslock") then
        repeat
            if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
                repeat
                    PressAndReleaseKey("p")
                    Sleep(10)
                        for i = 1, 20 do
                            MoveMouseRelative(10,0)
                        end
                        for i = 1,20 do
                            MoveMouseRelative(-10,0)
                        end
                until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
            end
        until not IsKeyLockOn("capslock")
    end
end
```

This code does the same thing basically and it does it in the way I want pretty much. The problem is, when I hold down my mouse button for long, when I release the mouse button my mouse is still moving from left to right for a while. So I need a way to make it so that when I release my mouse button it stops moving from left to right no matter what.

Comment: insert statement `if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end` inside each of your loops "for i = 1,20 do"

Comment: Thanks, will try when I get home

Comment: Hey @EgorSkriptunoff, that line of code helped greatly. However I have another problem. The mouse is moving really shaky. Id like it to be a smoother movement kinda from left to right. Do you have any idea what I could do to smooth the movement.

Comment: For a smooth movement you should repeat "move a bit + sleep a bit" in a loop.

Comment: Ok thank you I'll implement that now. But I have another question. I want the script to also move down a little. But when I add -1 to the y axis it begins to move down extremely fast. I want it to move down at a slower speed than the speed at which it is moving left to right. Do you have a suggestion for that @EgorSkriptunoff

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff When I add the sleep in the loop I get the same issue as in Code#1, It makes it so that P is pressed at a slower rate. But i need P to be pressed fast while the mouse moves left to right slower

Comment: So, do you want pressing "P" key be not synchronized with mouse movement?

Comment: Yeah pretty much that’s what I wanted. But I ended up figuring it out. Basically all I had to do was put the pressing P in its own loop and then it stopped synchronizing with mouse movement. Thank you so much for all the help

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Ok i have one more problem. This script begins to make whatever program Im using lag heavilly when i actually use it and press down mouse button 1. Do you have any idea why.

Comment: Remove `repeat...until not IsKeyLockOn("capslock")`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Alright that did help to alleviate the lag so it is bearable now. Thank you. Regarding your earlier comment about making the mouse move smoothly, could you elaborate more on what you mean by repeating move a bit + sleep a bit in a loop. Are you saying that in the loop for "for i = 1, 20 do" i should write multiple movemouserelatives and sleeps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Regarding your earlier comment about making the mouse move smoothly, could you elaborate more on what you mean by repeating move a bit + sleep a bit in a loop.

Here is an example how to make smoothest mouse movement

First, define the following function before `OnEvent`:

```
function SmoothMouseMovement(x_speed, y_speed, duration)
    local last_x, last_y = 0, 0
    local tm_start = GetRunningTime()
    repeat
        Sleep(5)
        if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        local tm = math.min(GetRunningTime() - tm_start, duration)
        local x = math.floor(x_speed * tm)
        local y = math.floor(y_speed * tm)
        if x ~= last_x or y ~= last_y then
            MoveMouseRelative(x - last_x, y - last_y)
            last_x = x
            last_y = y
        end
    until tm >= duration
end
```

Second, replace your old loops `for i = 1,20 do` with the following code:

```
local x_speed = 1.5  -- pixels per millisecond
local duration = 200 -- milliseconds
SmoothMouseMovement(x_speed, 0, duration)
local x_speed = -1.5  -- pixels per millisecond
local duration = 200  -- milliseconds
SmoothMouseMovement(x_speed, 0, duration)
```

Comment: Ok I really like that example, I just tested it and I think when I finish it will work really well. But when I use the example code, P begins to press slower, even when i put it in its own loop, so using that example doesn't work with the fix I found before. So now, P is being pressed in sync with the mouse again. Do you think there is a way to use that code, while also making P press at a different pace

Comment: I have tried putting the mouse movement code into its own loop, into its own function but it either stops working, or P begins to press in sync with the movement.

Comment: Regarding the Second section of the code too.  How do i go about adding movement of the y axis to it.